# Given formula to calculate sum of first n terms of a sequence, show that the sequence is geometric

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there anything wrong with the following method to show that the sequence is geometric?

[image]

It seems wrong because it uses the generic formula for sum of first n terms of a geometric progression (GP) and thus is assuming "sequence is a GP before proving it":

$S_n = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$

But on the other hand, I can't think of another sequence that would result in the "formula to calculate sum of first n terms of a sequence" to be of this form:

$S_n = 3(1-(\frac{1}{3})^n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method indeed appears to assume what is to be proved.
I don't see an easy way to explain away that problem in the equations as presented.

On the other hand, consider your procedure as a method for guessing what the geometric progression might be. You obtained the guess $ar^n$ where
$$\begin{eqnarray}
r &=& \frac 13,\\
a &=& 3(1 - r) = 2.
\end{eqnarray}$$
Now compute the sum of the first $n$ terms of the geometric progression $2\left(\frac 13\right)^n.$
Is that sum $3(1 - 3^{-n})?$
If so, then $2\left(\frac 13\right)^n$ is the correct sequence,
for this reason:
if $S_{n - 1}$ and $S_n$ are respectively the sums of the first $n - 1$ and the 
first $n$ terms of a sequence, respectively, then the $n$th term of that sequence
is $S_n - S_{n - 1};$ that is, the series of sums of a sequence uniquely determines
the sequence; and the formula $3(1 - 3^{-n})$ describes the complete series of sums
of the desired sequence.

This still seems a bit clumsy when you have the alternative to compute
$S_n - S_{n - 1}$ directly, as in the answer by Vikram.

Answer (score 4):

The method alluded above computes thee value of $r$ and $a_1$ **assuming** that the sequence is geometric.

To show the sequence is geometric, notice that $a_n= S_n-S_{n-1}$, where $S_k$ denotes the $k$th partial sum.

Answer (score 1):

$S_n=3(1-3^{-n}) \therefore S_{n-1}=3\left(1-3^{-(n-1)}\right)$

nth term$=S_n-S_{n-1}=3(1-3^{-n})-3\left(1-3^{-(n-1)}\right)=3\left(1-3^{-n}-1+3^{-n+1}\right)=\frac{2}{3^{n-1}}$

$\therefore \text{(n-1)th term}=\frac{2}{3^{n-2}}$

$\therefore r=\frac{\text{nth term}}{\text{(n-1) th term}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

I think this formula works a_n=a_1*r^n-1
a_1 is the first term ,r is the common ratio,n is the number of term
so -6,-24,-78,-243
so the common ratio is 3 and first term =-6.I don't whether it is correct or not.